# vb.net System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException When Trying to ping

Tags: vb.net

been trying to follow this guide on how to make picture boxes change colour depending on if the ping has been successful or not. I have some test ip's in a CSV file that the program imports

but I keep getting a exception error. I have 3 picture boxes on the page currently defined from picturebox2 - 4

[image]

the code for the whole page is below, any suggestions or fixes would be greatly appreciated

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Timers


Public Class Central
    Dim pingTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim ipAddress As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Dim pictureBoxList As List(Of PictureBox) = New List(Of PictureBox)
    Dim timer As Timers.Timer

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        timer = New Timers.Timer
        timer.Interval = 20000
        timer.Enabled = True
        AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnElapsedTime

    End Sub
    Private Sub OnElapsedTime(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillPingTable()
        pingTable.Columns.Add("ip", GetType(String))
        pingTable.Columns.Add("picturebox", GetType(String))
        pingTable.Rows.Add()
        For i As Integer = 0 To ipAddress.Count - 1
            pingTable.Rows.Add(ipAddress(i), pictureBoxList(i))
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Hide()
        Scot.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Hide()
        Home.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub central_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Using reader = New StreamReader("A:\IpAddress.csv")
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                Dim line = reader.ReadLine
                Dim values = line.Split(ChrW(10))
                ipAddress.Add(values(0))
            End While

            For i As Integer = 1 To 2
                pictureBoxList.Add(CType(Controls.Find("PictureBox" & i, True)(0), PictureBox))
                FillPingTable()
                BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

            Next
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Thread.Sleep(500)
        Parallel.For(0, ipAddress.Count(), Sub(i, loopState)
                                               Dim ping As New Ping()
                                               Dim pingReply As PingReply = ping.Send(ipAddress(i).ToString())
                                               Me.BeginInvoke(CType(Sub()
                                                                        pictureBoxList(i).SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                                                                        pictureBoxList(i).BackColor = If(pingReply.Status = IPStatus.Success, Color.Green, Color.Red)
                                                                    End Sub, Action))
                                           End Sub)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have two pictureboxes in `pictureBoxList`, and you have an unspecified number of strings in `ipAddress`.

Comment: The error message specifically states that you used an index outside the valid range. Did you bother to look to see what the index was and what the range was when the exception was thrown, because you certainly haven't told us at least one of those things?

Comment: Why are you calling `FillPingTable` and starting your `BackgroundWorker` multiple times while populating `pictureBoxList`? Surely you should be doing once at the end at most. That is what happens when you write code without a clear idea of the steps the code needs to perform. You end up with code doing nonsensical things. If you have an actual algorithm before writing the code, you always have something to compare it to.